# Can I modify the width of indenting in Eclipse's Package Explorer view of folders?

Tags: eclipse

I have to work with a project structure like this:

```
* Projectname
    * src1
    * src2
    * folder1
        * folderlib
            * src
                * com
                    * example2
                        * some
                            * client
                                ISomeFoo.java
                                SomeFoo.java
                                BarConnection.java
```

I like to keep the package explorer open to get a glimpse on where am I (*Link with Editor* on) but *the fold-indenting takes up too much space*. While it's never good [imho](http://www.wordnik.com/words/IMHO), it starts to become a bit uncomfortable when I would like to compare something in my code with some reference (like a tutorial, a spec, docs or an info in an email). Especially when I use auro snap the window to (say, left) half of the screen, what I tend to do.

While it is not a major blocker it's slightly irritating and I wonder if there is a way to adjust the indenting width? Or an alternative plugin to package explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your Package Explorer's Package Presentation to Flat from its local menu (the upside-down triangle), which will present the packages in your Source Folders as a list of package names rather than an indenting folder hierarchy.  Once that's done, you can also set up package compression (to replace com.example2.something with c.e2.s throughout the UI for example) in the Java Appearance preference page.

Comment: I've already experimented with it. Unfortunately I'm already running flat. But this made me double check and so I noticed that I'm viewing a nested eclipse project that is not being recognized and eclipse views it as a folder only. I shall `import...` it so eclipse recognizes it. While not answering my question, still it solves my problem. +1 I'll leave the question open in case maybe someone needs real indent-width change.